# Variables in for loop can not be returned?

Tags: c#

I know this is very basic, but I really cannot see where is the problem in this code

```
        private int Linesel(List<GraphicsPath> LineGroup)
    {
        int selectedline;
        for (int i =0; i < LineGroup.Count; i++)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Navy, 8);
            if (LineGroup[i].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen))
            {
                selectedline = i;

            }
            else if (!LineGroup[i].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen))
            {
                selectedline = -1;

            }

        }
        return selectedline;
    }
```

The return variable is informed as a error by the complier.
What mistake have I made

Comment: Maybe showing what the error is?...

Comment: `selectedline` is not definitely assigned. Perhaps initialize to -1? It is quite possible to go through your loop *without setting a value to selectedline*.

Comment: I guess the error is "Use of unassigned local variable selectedLine".

Comment: set selectedline to zero!

Comment: Errors thrown by the compiler are there to help you. "Use of unassigned local variable selectedLine" is saying "you're potentially using a local variable that hasn't been assigned". What would the solution to that question be? Assign a value to the variable. Try it and see if it it fixes the issue. Compilers and debuggers are powerful, take advantage of them :)

Comment: Although you assume that your loop is allways executed because `LineGroup.Count` is *allways* greater zero, the compiler can´t know that as it has no lknowldge on the elements within your list. Thus the iteration may or may not be executed (at least from the view of the compiler) and thus the variable may stay unitialized.

Comment: I agree the question as asked is a dupe of the canonical "Unassigned local" question, but the OPs problems here run deeper than that question, such that I believe he needs an original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is, when your for loop has no iterations *(LineGroup.Count == 0)*, `selectedline` has no value. The compiler  You could solve it with:

```
int selectedline = default(int);
```

---

Like Scott said, `0` is also a valid value. You could solve it two ways.

- returning a not valid but detectable value.

  ```
  private int Linesel(List<GraphicsPath> LineGroup)
  {
      for (int i =0; i < LineGroup.Count; i++)
      {
          Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Navy, 8);
          if (LineGroup[i].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen))
          {
              return i;
          }
      }

      return -1;
  }
  ```

  **OR**

  ```
  private int? Linesel(List<GraphicsPath> LineGroup)
  {
      for (int i =0; i < LineGroup.Count; i++)
      {
          Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Navy, 8);
          if (LineGroup[i].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen))
          {
              return i;
          }
      }

      return null;
  }
  ```

  use it like:

  ```
  var res = Linesel(....);
  if(!res.HasValue)
  {
      // problem
  }
  else
  {
      // ->   res.Value;
  }
  ```

---

- Raising an exception

  ```
  private int Linesel(List<GraphicsPath> LineGroup)
  {
      for (int i =0; i < LineGroup.Count; i++)
      {
          Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Navy, 8);
          if (LineGroup[i].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen))
          {
              return i;
          }
      }

      throw new Exception("WHATEVER"); // <-- you might create your own 
  }
  ```

Comment: I would be careful of `default(int)`, that would return `0` which is a vailid value for `selectedline`, you likely should use some other value that can't be returned by the `for` loop to indicate no line was selected.

Comment: That's why I always copy my long posts in to notepad before submitting them.

Comment: Yep, I did, it is still in my notepad... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to execute that code without ever setting a value for `selectedline` if there are no items in the `LineGroup` collection.

Additionally, with the `if ()` and `else if()` blocks, the compiler is not smart enough to know that the condition for the `else if()` block is the opposite of the condition from the original `if ()` block, and so the compiler can't be sure you will ever hit either of the assignment statements even when you do have items in the collection. It may be obvious to human programmers, but the compiler doesn't work the same way. Much better to just do an `else` here rather than make the cpu re-test the condition anyway.

This code should run closer to what you expected:

```
private int Linesel(List<GraphicsPath> LineGroup)
{
    int selectedline = -1;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Navy, 8);
    for (int i =0; i < LineGroup.Count; i++)
    {
        selectedline = LineGroup[i].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen)?i:-1;
    }
    return selectedline;
}
```

Finally, you do understand that only the **last element** of `LineGroup` really matters to this code, right? You may have many lines in the group, but you only return one integer. The code checks ALL of the lines, and sets the `selectedline` every time, but only the *final* value of `selectedline` is returned to the caller. If that's really what you want, then so be it, but if that's the case you should use code more like this:

```
private int Linesel(List<GraphicsPath> LineGroup)
{
    int last = LineGroup.Count -1;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Navy, 8);
    return LineGroup[last].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen)?last:-1;
}
```

Trying to guess at your real intent, the best I can do is you want to know the last line that is actually visible. In that case, just avoid the else entirely:

```
private int Linesel(List<GraphicsPath> LineGroup)
{
    int selectedline = -1;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Navy, 8);
    for (int i =0; i < LineGroup.Count; i++)
    {
        if (LineGroup[i].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen))
            selectedline = i;
    }
    return selectedline;
}
```